# Angular 9 SSR build throws error for NgLocaleLocalization

Tags: angular, ivy, ng-bootstrap, angular-universal, angular9

So I have a complex Angular project hosted in firebase. Till now, I was doing a normal Client side rendering and recently I moved on SSR and upgraded my project to Angular 9 version. When I run `ng build --prod --aot && ng run myproject:server:production` and when I run `node dist/server/main` it throws below error when I try to access the `localhost:port`.

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for NgLocaleLocalization: (?).
    at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory (\MyProject\dist\server\main.js:1:4440360)     
    at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (\MyProject\dist\server\main.js:1:4441186)   
    at providerToFactory (\MyProject\dist\server\main.js:1:4442452)
    at providerToRecord (\MyProject\dist\server\main.js:1:4438546)
    at R3Injector.processProvider (\MyProject\dist\server\main.js:1:4438606)
    at provider (\MyProject\dist\server\main.js:1:4438102)
    at input.forEach.value (\MyProject\dist\server\main.js:1:4326776)
    at Array.forEach ()
    at deepForEach (\MyProject\dist\server\main.js:1:4326718)
    at R3Injector.processInjectorType (\MyProject\dist\server\main.js:1:4438062)
```

But when I just run `ng serve` it runs fine without any issues. So I suspect the issue is with SSR build. It was not there until I switched to Angular 9. `Ivy` could be the reason too. But as far as I've read through angular's official site, I never extend `NgLocaleLocalization` class from `@angular/common` anywhere in my app.

I also tried to provide `NgLocalization` as a provider in `app.module`, but even that didn't help. 
Nowhere in google anyone reported or mentioned this problem. I've also created an issue in **[github repo](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1622)** but no one responded till now. I am totally out of options.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.2",
    "@ks89/angular-modal-gallery": "^7.2.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.2.6",
    "angular-count-to": "0.0.3",
    "angular-tilt": "^1.2.0",
    "angular-typing-animation": "^0.5.4",
    "animate-scss": "^3.2.1",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^7.14.1",
    "firebaseui": "4.5.0",
    "firebaseui-angular": "^4.1.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.4.3",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.28",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.5",
    "ng-animate": "^0.3.4",
    "ng2-animate-on-scroll": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.12",
    "ng2-scroll-to-el": "^1.2.1",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.2.4",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^9.0.6",
    "ngx-content-loading": "^0.1.3",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-logger": "^4.1.5",
    "ngx-masonry": "^9.1.1",
    "ngx-masonry-gallery": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
    "razorpay": "^2.0.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
    "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.10.12",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.2",
    "@types/express-serve-static-core": "^4.17.5",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.3",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/mousetrap": "^1.6.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.11.1",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.4",
    "replace-in-file": "^5.0.2",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.3.1",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.8.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "ws": "^7.2.3",
    "xhr2": "^0.2.0"
  }
```

Any idea what this error actually talks about? How this could be resolved or what else I got to try? :)

Any advice/suggestions/resolutions are kindly appreciated.

---

**Update** - TBH, I do not use localization in my app and hence I went on debugging from where the issue was coming, then I found out that I use `ng-bootstrap` which requires `@angular/localize` package to be included. But even after this, I am not able to get the resolution for this.

Comment: Did you find some solution of your problem?

Comment: @DineshRawat I think I just updated all the dependencies and that resolved the issue most likely.. :)

Comment: I will give it a try, I am trying to find the exact module causing this problem. For me it may be quill editor

Comment: Yea.. It was a hard time investigating the root cause..

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/i18n/localization.ts) for `NgLocaleLocalization`, you'll see that it needs the `LOCALE_ID` token

```
@Injectable()
export class NgLocaleLocalization extends NgLocalization {
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) protected locale: string) {
    super();
  }
```

Maybe try providing this in your code

```
providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US' }] //Or any other language
```

If that works, then provide the locale based on a factory if needed

Comment: Well, I did try adding this in `app.module.ts`, but unfortunately, no luck. Still the error is being thrown.. :(

Comment: Did you find any solution?